# Is react-native animation jittery on frequent updates of redux state?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

My list view presents a stack of cards that is scrolled horizontally. At most, three cards are visible in the view with the outer most cards on the left and right fading in and out as a function of the user scrolling horizontally.

I calculate which cards are suppose to fade-in/out as the user scrolls utilizing the internal list view API to check and continually update redux state as a result.

The problem is the scrolling animation experience is inconsistent. It jitters when I scroll sometimes and other times it is smooth. Sometimes the fade in out functionality bugs out or updates a few seconds later after a scroll. What gives?

Is jittery animation normally expected when the redux state is updated frequently?

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the code which is creating the issue.